# Install packages with pip in a different version of Python

Tags: python, package, python-2.6

I have to run a script in Python2.6 but usually I work with Python3.8.0. I have installed the older version, added a new environment variable and changed the name of the python file to python26, so this way I can run the old version using the command `python26 script.py`. The curren directory where it is installed is `C:\Python26`.

How can I install packages using pip for this old version?

Comment: You can both use a virtualenv, or install using pip3 for python3

Answer (score 0):

Use as below in your command line.

**If windows:**

/your/python/dir/python*.exe -m pip install

So yours would be like in cmd prompt:

```
C:\Python26\python.exe -m pip install <your-package-here>
```

**If Linux:**

/your/python/dir/python* -m pip install

`*` Represents any version of python with extension.

python3.8 or python or python2.7

Comment: I am using windows. I does not work, the output is ```C:\Python26\python26.exe: No module named pip```

Comment: So, you need to install pip

Comment: Download or copy paste the file from this link. https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
Then run python get-pip.py file.

Comment: This will install pip and you can proceed with the above mentioned command.

Comment: I've tryed downloading the file, executing it with python 3.8.0 without problem, but the next step does not work. I've already try to install it with python26 but an error appears (SyntaxError).

Comment: No, I want you to run python this way ```C:\Python26\python26.exe get-pip.py```, for your python26 which you are trying to install. It is the one which is missing the pip files.

Comment: This is the way I did it and the SyntaxError appears.

Comment: Can you show what you tried and what error you got? Otherwise it will be hard to troubleshoot for me.

Comment: ```C:\Python26\python26.exe get-pip.py``` as command, the output:

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 22318, in <module>
  [...]
"c:\users\mgijon\appdata\local\temp\tmpb1kpgh\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 105
    binary_only = FormatControl(set(), {':all:'})
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: Basically the error is this current version of get-pip file, is there another way to install the libraries avoiding use pip?

Comment: Yes, That is correct. I did my research and found out that python2.6 exclusively requires different set of installation tools.

Use the below link to get setuptools.py

https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/04/be569e393006fa9a2c10ef72ea33133c2902baa115dd1d4279dae55c3b3b/setuptools-36.8.0.zip

After that run. ``` python2.6 setup.py install ``` 

Then get-pip.py should install pip for you.  

The last version of pip supporting Python 2.6 is 9.0.3: https://pypi.org/project/pip/9.0.3/#files

Comment: If you can upgrade your python version. I would suggest you to do so, Because Unless you have a legacy system, You don't need to punish your fellow members

Comment: I've run the ```setup.py install``` but ```get-pip.py``` does not work. Same mistake. And yes, unfortunately it is in fact a legacy system I can not get rid of it. Thanks for the help

Comment: You can follow the final steps one last time after uninstalling python2.6

Comment: I've repeat all the process twice and the output is always the same  mistake.

Comment: Sorry mate, I tried my best to help you but it didn't quite workout

Comment: Thanks for the help and for don't give up, If i solve the problem I will post it here.

Comment: @ManuelG. Thanks! And best of luck for your endeavors.